# Rollback to previous commits to find when bug was introduced

Tags: git, github

I have this bug that showed up in my iOS app somewhere in the last 10 commits. I've tried looking at every single change I've made using a diff tool but can't figure it out.

Now I want to roll back to every version one by one to find what was the last version that did not have a bug, hoping that that way I can single out the problem.

What is the best way to rollback to the previous versions while keeping my latest commit safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) for tracking down bugs.

The general idea is, if you have a rough idea of when a bug appeared, git can do a binary search for the commit that caused the bug. The documentation has lots of examples and detailed explanation. A quick example:

```sh
git bisect # Start the bisect process
git bisect bad # This tells git bisect that the current commit is "bad", as in the bug is exhibited
git bisect good <commit hash> # This tells git bisect that <commit hash> doesn't exhibit the bug, so we only need to search between "good" and "bad". This would be your commit hash from 10 commits ago as mentioned in your question.
```

After that, git will check out a commit. You would then compile it, run it, whatever, then use `git bisect good` or `git bisect bad` to tell git whether or not the bug is exhibited. It will use this feedback to pin down the exact commit that introduced the "bad" behavior.

You can also use `git bisect reset` to cancel the bisect process.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was the most complete response. Managed to find when and where the bug was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

The best you could try is bisecting. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to roll back every commit. Use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

> This command uses a binary search algorithm to find which commit in 
>   your project’s history introduced a bug. You use it by first telling
>   it a "bad" commit that is known to contain the bug, and a "good"
>   commit that is known to be before the bug was introduced. Then git
>   bisect picks a commit between those two endpoints and asks you whether
>   the selected commit is "good" or "bad". It continues narrowing down
>   the range until it finds the exact commit that introduced the change.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a branch pointing at your latest commit, it’s safe as long as you don’t move that branch. If you don’t have a branch at your latest commit, you need to create one with `git branch <new_branch_name>`.

In this case, you don’t need to look at *every* commit, and if you have a good automated test for the bug you don’t need to manually look at any commit except the one that failed. You can instead use [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout a previous commit with `git checkout <commit_hash>`